# R data frame remove column using grep - columns don't get remove

Tags: r, dataframe

I have following loop:

```
columns.to.remove <- c('C_', 'WWTest_', 'TotalClick', 'IPA_', 'Sell', 'G_')
for (i in length(columns.to.remove)) {

  final.frame <- final.frame[, -grep(columns.to.remove[i], colnames(final.frame))]
}
```

But when i look at the data frame by trying to do `final.frame$G_` its still shows up as all.

Comment: Don't do this in a loop. Just do `final.frame <- final.frame[, -grep(columns.to.remove, colnames(final.frame))]`

Comment: @MrFlick - How would that work?  `grep()` doesn't accept a vector of length > 1 in `pattern`.

Comment: @DirtySockSniffer My bad. I meant to swap `grep` for `match`. Get all the matches at once. So `final.frame[,-match(columns.to.remove, colnames(final.frame))]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (i in columns.to.remove) {
    final.frame <- final.frame[!grepl(i, colnames(final.frame))]
}
```

### Edit: Doing this without a loop

```
columns.to.remove.combined <- paste(columns.to.remove, collapse = '|')
final.frame <- final.frame[!grepl(columns.to.remove.combined, colnames(final.frame))]
```